# Cumulative subtraction with two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I have the table where I have 2 values for each day. I need to subtract the Val1 - Val2 row by row. E.g.:

```
          day   Val1    Val2
1    20230310    100     50
2    20230311    NaN     10
3    20230312    NaN      5
4    20230313    NaN     -3
5    20230314    NaN     40
```

How it should look like at the end:

```
          day   Val1    Val2
1    20230310    100     10
2    20230311     50     50
3    20230312     45      5
4    20230313     48     -3
5    20230314      8     40
```

Below is the same example but with the logic, not only the results:

```
          day   Val1        Val2
1    20230310    100         10
2    20230311    100-50=50   50
3    20230312    50-5=45      5
4    20230313    45-(-3)=48  -3
5    20230314    48-40=8     40
```

Comment: why is the 10 unused? where is the 8 coming from?

Comment: My mistake, I've changed that to be more correct

Comment: Why were 10 and 50 swapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Val1'] = df['Val1'].fillna(-df['Val2']).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
        day   Val1  Val2
1  20230310  100.0    10
2  20230311   50.0    50
3  20230312   45.0     5
4  20230313   48.0    -3
5  20230314    8.0    40
```